# SQL Debit, Credit, Balance

Tags: mysql, sql

hi i am trying to figure out what SQL statement i should use to produce this output. i tried my best but my queries didnt work. thanks

```
STUDNO  | DEBIT  | CREDIT | BALANCE
1001    | 10000  |        | 10000
1001    |        |  5000  | 5000
1001    | 50     |        | 5050
1002    | 50     |        | 50
1003    | 0      | 0      |0 


these are the tables.

TBLSTUDENTS
ID   | NAME
1001 | A
1002 | B
1003 |



TBLPAYABLES
ID | Studno | Partic| Amount
1  | 1001   | TF    | 10,000
2  | 1001   | ID    | 50     
3  | 1002   | ID    |50

TBLPAYMENTS
ID | Studno  | Amount
1  | 1001    | 5000
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What have you come up to this far? Please show us your current select and describe what's wrong with it!

Comment: Show your queries otherwise a cynical person might suspect you're just trying to get someone else to do your homework.

Comment: TF and ID are paticulars
TF= tuition fee and  ID = id itself

Comment: What are the sorting conditions? Why one `CREDIT` row is between two `DEBIT` rows?

Comment: @rtruszk the credit between two debits are the payment of student 1001
our professors told us that it has zigzag pattern, in first row a debit of 10000 minus 
a credit of 0 equals 10000. in second column a balance of 10000(from 1st column) minus a credit of 5000 (since student 1001 pay an amount of 5000, see tblpayments) is equal to 5000. and a balance of 5000(2nd column) plus a debit of 50 is equal to 5050.

Comment: I guess she wants the CREDIT and DEBIT row to be shown alternately

Comment: @coffeecat, which sql? which version? If it is MS SQL paste output from this query `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: It would be best if professor log into StackOverflow and specify his requirements.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri MYSQL

Comment: @rtruszk i hope i can tell that to our professor.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
select S.Studno, credit, Debit, row_number() Over (Partition by S.Studno, Order By ID as RN into #A
From
(
select S.Studno, null as credit, D.Amount as Debit
from TBLSTUDENTS S
left join  TBLPAYABLES D
union all
select S.Studno, C.Amount as credit, null as Debit, D.ID
left Join  TBLPAYMENTS C   
union all
select S.Studno, 0 as credit, 0 as Debit, 0
from TBLSTUDENTS S
where S.Studno not in (select Studno from TBLPAYABLES) or 
S.Studno not in (select Studno from TBLPAYMENTS)
) x

select S.Studno, Credit, Debit, C.ID        
( SELECT SUM(Coalesce(Debit,0) - Coalesce(Credit,0)) 
  FROM #A B
  WHERE A.Studno = B.Studno AND B.RN <= A.RN
) PrevSum
From #A A
order by S.Studno, RN
```